# Bash - eliminar nombres de las variables

Tags: bash, jq

Haciendo un sript con `jq`, obtengo el resultado siguiente:

```
Women
--------------
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":5.6,"V9":3}
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":5.6,"V9":3}
{"V1":32,"V2":"Female","V8":6,"V9":3}
{"V1":31,"V2":"Female","V8":6,"V9":3}
{"V1":19,"V2":"Female","V8":5.5,"V9":3}
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":7,"V9":3}
{"V1":20,"V2":"Female","V8":6.1,"V9":3}
{"V1":32,"V2":"Female","V8":7,"V9":3}
{"V1":42,"V2":"Female","V8":6.7,"V9":3}
 
Men
-------------
{"V1":72,"V2":"Male","V8":7.4,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":6.3,"V9":3}
{"V1":33,"V2":"Male","V8":5.4,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":6.8,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":7.4,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":7,"V9":3}
{"V1":72,"V2":"Male","V8":6.2,"V9":3}
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es

```
Women
--------------
38,Female,3, 5.6
38,Female,3, 5.6
32,Female,3, 6
31,Female,3, 6
19,Female,3, 5.5
38,Female,3, 7
20,Female,3, 6.1
32,Female,3, 7
42,Female,3, 6.7

Men
--------------
72,Male,3, 7.4
60,Male,3, 6.3
33,Male,3, 5.4
60,Male,3, 6.8
60,Male,3, 7.4
60,Male,3, 7
72,Male,3, 6.2
```

El script que tengo hecho es el siguiente:

```
echo "Women";
echo "--------------";
cat csvjson.json | jq -c '.[] | {V1, V2, V8, V9} | select(.V9 ==3) | select(.V2 =="Female")';
echo " "
echo "Men";
echo "-------------";
cat csvjson.json | jq -c '.[] | {V1, V2, V8, V9} | select(.V9 ==3) | select(.V2 =="Male")';
```

El archivo json se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
[
  {
    "V1": 65,
    "V2": "Female",
    "V3": 0.7,
    "V4": 0.1,
    "V5": 187,
    "V6": 16,
    "V7": 18,
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.3,
    "V10": 0.9,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 10.9,
    "V4": 5.5,
    "V5": 699,
    "V6": 64,
    "V7": 100,
    "V8": 7.5,
    "V9": 3.2,
    "V10": 0.74,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 7.3,
    "V4": 4.1,
    "V5": 490,
    "V6": 60,
    "V7": 68,
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3,
    "V10": 0.89,
    "Class": 1
  },
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué contiene exactamente el fichero csvjson.json? No me queda claro qué viene del echo y qué del fichero

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', añado en la consulta lo que hay dentro del fichero json. Al menos una parte de ello, tienes razón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este caso `jq` cuenta con un funcionalidad llamada [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29).

Básicamente dice que dentro de una cadena (`"bla bla bla"`) se colocan las llaves (`.V1, .V2,...`) pero cada una de esta llaves, encerradas entre paréntesis y con una barra invertida

En tal sentido bastaría realizar lo siguiente:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.V2=="Male") | "\(.V1), \(.V2), \(.V8), \(.V9)"' csvjson.json
```

Resultado con el `json` compartido:

```
"62, Male, 7.5, 3.2"
"62, Male, 7, 3.3"
```

y luego cambiar "Female" por "Male" haciendo quizás un loop `for gender in Female Male`... e insertarlo en un archivo `csv`

Como nota final, si ves las sintaxis `\(.V1)` sería muy similar a usar el símbolo dólar `$()` en vez de la barra invertida, para correr dentro de ella una expresión y obtener la salida

```
echo "hoy es $(date)"

# hoy es Sun Oct 24 19:13:53 -05 2021
```

Comment: Esto sería equivalente a hacer cut? Estaba pensando en que cut sería una buena opción pero no tengo claro cómo hacerlo y veo que esta opción es buena también. (Tendría que añadir ```.V9==3``` también en todo caso)

Comment: La verdad no uso `cut` con `json` si puedo hacerlo con `jq`, si quisiera usar `cut` no lo veo tan directo... supon el string `\"{\"V1\":38\,\"V2\":\"Female\"\,\"V8\":5.6\,\"V9\":3}\"` (`escapar de las "`) tendrías que usar la expresión `| cut -d "," -f 1 | cut -d ":" -f 2` donde el primer cut parte el string por las comas. El segundo `cut` toma la parte del string de interés después de ":" (falla al final) Quizás aplicando un regex que extraiga (o reemplace) los datos de interés sea mejor. Te sugiero que plantees esta duda como otra pregunta y así obtengas una respuesta mejor a la mía.